# IF statement condensing multiple OR statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the following line

```
if 'smoke' in row['product'].lower() or 'grill' in row['product'].lower() or 'choco' in row['product'].lower():
```

I want to add multiple items in the OR clause. ['smoke', 'grill, 'choco', ...], how can I condense the if statement while not losing the logic?

Comment: assign each condition to a separate variable.  or use a dict.

Comment: What exactly might `row[product].lower()` return?

Comment: @NChauhan it will produce the product name as a string ex: 'greatest-chopper'

Comment: So, do you want to check whether `'smoke'` appears within the name such as `'smoked-fish'` or whether the name _is_ the value exactly?

Comment: @NChauhan whether it appears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generator expression with `any`:

```
if any(item in row['product'].lower() for item in ("smoke", "grill", "choco")):
```

Comment: And the OP can separate the tuple as an assigned variable, shortening the `if` line.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `any`

```
if any(item in row['product'].lower()
       for item in ('choco', 'smoke', 'grill'):
```

Or if `row['product'].lower()` is a string and you want to compare whether they are identical or not:

```
if row['product'].lower() in ('choco', 'grill', 'smoke'):
```

Where I have the tuple of the names, replace this with a pre-written list of strings like so:

```
names = ('choco', 'grill', 'smoke', ...)
if row['product'].lower() in names:
```

Comment: Your 2nd suggestion does not quite do the same thing as the first one. You're checking if `row['product']` is exactly identical to any of the 3 words, not if it *contains* any of the 3 words.

Comment: Yes, considered this, but it depends on the OP's data as well to choose which one is suitable.